# phase equilibrium

Tags: physical-chemistry

Is partial pressure in vapor phase is the same as vapor pressure?

pure vapor pressure of x and y are given. 
and i know we have to find the mole fraction times with the purevapor pressure to find vapor pressure. 
then, the question also gives partial pressure of x and y in vapor phase and asked whether the systm exhibit negative or postive deiviation from raoult's law.

so what is the use of the partial pressure?

Answer (score 0):

For an ideal liquid solution, Raoult's law predicts that the partial pressure of a species in the gas phase is equal to the mole fraction of the species in the liquid phase times the equilibrium vapor pressure which that species would exhibit if it were a pure liquid at the solution temperature.  If the liquid is not an ideal solution, the partial pressure in the gas phase will deviate from the prediction of Raoult's law.

Comment: A negative deviation: If the vapor pressure of a mixture is lower than that expected from Raoult's law.  A positive deviation:  The vapor pressure of the mixture is greater than that expected from the Raoult's law.